# Submitting input reveals second input but both fields sent to handler

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have a simple form with two fields. I'd like the second field to be hidden at first and then show when the button is clicked on the first field, but have the contents of both fields sent to me by the form handler.

The html I've got is something like:

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form" action="submit.php">
            <input id="URL" name="URL" type="text" placeholder="Website URL (www.yoursite.com)"><input type="submit" value="Submit!">
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address"><input type="submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

I'd like the second field, the email field to be hidden "behind" the URL field and when the URL field is filled out and clicked, the email field replaces it and when the email field is submitted, then the form is submitted with both fields sent. I'm not great with jQuery; is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// css
 .hidden{
  display: none;
}
// html
<form method="post" name="contact_form" action="submit.php">
            <input class="url" name="URL" type="text" placeholder="Website URL (www.yoursite.com)">
            <input class='url' type="submit" value="Submit!">
            <input class='hidden' name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address">
            <input type="submit" class="hidden" value="Send!">
</form>


//js

    function stopSubm(){
      $('form').one("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var count= 0;
        if (count > 0 ){
          $(this).submit();
        }
        $('.url').hide();
        $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        count++;


    });

  };
  stopSubm();
```

Comment: That totally rocks. Thanks. Very helpful. Works perfectly.